# Javascript loop issue

Tags: javascript, html, for-loop

Hey I have a problem with one loop: 
I need to put html into JavaScript because it is a meme.
Here is the code which is working fine but using document.write. I don't want use document.write as it is not working on Firefox:

```
for (var m = 1; m < 5; m++) {   
  document.write("<li onClick=\"hello2()\"><a href=\"#\"><script>document.write(wynik)<\/script><\/a><\/li>");
}
```

I tried to use:

```
document.getElementById('menu').innerHTML = "<li onClick=\"hello2()\"><a href=\"#\"><Script>document.write(wynik)<\/script><\/a><\/li>");
```

But it is not working porperly. Wrong format and showing only once in the loop.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why are you having javascript write a script tag?

Comment: i'm not a true fan of manipulating HTML content to the DOM with `.innerHTML`. I prefer [`createElement()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.createElement), [`appendChild()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.appendChild), [`removeChild()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.removeChild) ...

Comment: why is this for "<Script>document.write(wynik)<\/script>"? you are already scripting then just concate variable "wynik"

Comment: you can removeTag your tag and .append what ever tag you want to be added

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
document.getElementById('menu').innerHTML += "<li onClick=\"hello2()\"><a href=\"#\">" + wynik + "<\/a><\/li>";
```

Use `+=` and remove `)` then it will  get work..

Comment: That works.. But what about the second document.write which is inside this one ?? <Script>document.write(wynik)<\/script>

Comment: @user3324547 just use `wynik` direct, like `'...<a href=\"#\">'+wynik+'<\/a>...'`

Comment: Why you use `document.write` there ,Just write your variable only...That is `wynik`

Comment: wynik is result of some acitions before. It is variable.

Comment: what do you mean in clear html ?
like that <li onClick="hello2()"><a href="#"><Script>wynik</script></a></li>. Its not working

Comment: I suggest you first of all check your DOM if it has your "`wynik`" not the value that it contain,  then you have error in your string that you inserted may be syntax error of `" "`!!

Comment: Check your ( updated ) answer there was an error on your string you cannot write variable as string you have to pass it ..

Comment: document.getElementById('menu').innerHTML += "<li onClick=\"hello2()\"><a href=\"#\">" + wynik + "<\/a><\/li>";

Comment: it works fine like that but FIREFOX is getting undefined for that. I don't know why. I thought its only getting undefined for document.write.. Please Help

Comment: for result of that "<li onClick=\"hello2()\"><a href=\"#\">" + wynik + "<\/a><\/li>"

Comment: means to say that your whole `<li onClick=\"hello2()\"><a href=\"#\">" + wynik + "<\/a><\/li>` is undefined in FIREFOX ?

Comment: Sorry for that but i can't have installed `firefox` on my PC so i can't able to debug it. I suggest you to read about firefox for `innerHTML`

Comment: May be firefox not fully support to `inject dynamic` content from external sites using `.load()` !